# ServiceStack Swagger - Mark method as 'New' or 'Updated'

Tags: servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm probably going to get shot down in flames for asking this:

I want to mark endpoints in my API as 'New' or 'Updated' so when the developers look through my swagger UI they can see all of the recent additions.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't exist in the core Swagger-UI functionality or ServiceStack's Swagger support.

But, you can roll your own without too much effort. The trick is that the `Summary` and `Notes` properties of `RouteAttribute` support raw HTML.

Decorate your DTO like this:

```cs
static class Docs {
    public const string NewApi = @"<em class=""new-api"">New!</em> ";
}

[Route(...., Notes = Docs.NewApi + "Detailed description of DTO goes here")]
public class MyDto {  ...  }

// OR

[Route(...., Summary = Docs.NewApi + "Summary goes here")]
public class MyDto {  ...  }
```

Then you can add some CSS to your swagger-ui index.html:

```
.new-api {
    background-color: #ffff00;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Now you can just append that string constant to the `Notes` or `Summary` property on the appropriate Route attributes, and it will appear as a styled marker on the Swagger UI. Of course you will need to manually add/remove these markers as you make changes to your DTOs, but it's pretty simple to implement.

Comment: Works sweetly for declaring deprecated methods aswell

Comment: Note that I think the latest version of ServiceStack includes a major Swagger update, which could provide more direct means of these sorts of customizations.